# How can I align my photo and text next to each other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-5

The thing that I am trying to do is: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkh7f.png)

The problem in my code is, I am using bootsrap grid system to achieve this easily but when I put this two text and image in a grid system(rows and columns), they look like this: [problematic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbeG0.png). How can I achieve the look in the first photograph I put? Also, I want my website to be responsive. So, please write an answer accordingly. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Own CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stayil.css">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bati Gozen</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <header id="home">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Batı Gözen</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#mywork">My Work</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#resume">CV</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Explanation !!!!!!!!I HAVE PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!-->
        <div class="container-fluid text-center mt-3">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <img src="images/IMG_0109.jpg" alt="My Picture" class="img-fluid myimage">
                    <h1 class="name mt-4 mb-3">Batı Gözen</h1>
                    <p class="caption">"Web Developer, Mix&Masterig Specialist"</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center ib-section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="col-6"><img class="img-fluid ib" src="images/ibimag.png" alt="IB"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 m-auto">
                    <h3 class="img-fluid"> IB Student, 12.th Grade</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Photo Gallery -->
    <section id="mywork">
        <h3>My Work</h3>
        <div class="continer-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <img src="images/1.png" alt="Certificate" class="basari">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <img src="images/2.png" alt="Certificate" class="basari">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="Certificate" class="basari">
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="row paddingekle">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <img src="images/1.png" alt="Certificate" class="basari">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <img src="images/5.png" alt="Certificate" class="basari">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="Certificate" class="basari">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Resume -->
    <section id="resume">
        <h3>My Resume</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-light">

            <a href="images/Bati's+Resume+(4).pdf" class="pdf"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i> Download</a>
        </button>
    </section>
    <!-- Bootsrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #CDF0EA;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}



.ib-section {
  margin: 60px 0;
}

.ib {
  max-width: 200px;
}



.name {
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}

.caption {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

.myimage {
  max-width: 18%;
  border-radius: 14%;
}

.navbar-brand,
.nav-link {
  color: #555555;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.nav-link:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want these elements grouped closely, it makes sense to nest them in the same parent and use `flex` only on that parent.

Instead of making them in two different `.col`'s. Try putting them in the same one and use `.d-flex` with `.align-items-center` and `.justify-content-center` classes on that parent. You can then use `.gap-3` for `1rem` of gap betwen the two elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: #CDF0EA;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.ib-section {
  margin: 60px 0;
}

.ib {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.name {
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}

.caption {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

.myimage {
  max-width: 18%;
  border-radius: 14%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Explanation !!!!!!!!I HAVE PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!-->
<div class="container-fluid text-center mt-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="My Picture" class="img-fluid myimage">
      <h1 class="name mt-4 mb-3">Batı Gözen</h1>
      <p class="caption">"Web Developer, Mix&Masterig Specialist"</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid text-center ib-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center gap-3">
      <img class="img-fluid ib" src="https://dummyimage.com/100/000/fff" alt="IB">
      <h3 class="img-fluid"> IB Student, 12.th Grade</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Last question. How can I edit this code to make it responsive? Normally I do col-lg-6 col-md-12 something like that. Now, what can I do?